# Why does Typescript report a length of 0 when there are 2 items in the array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

The response from a Firestore onSnapshot is 2 records which I push into an array named shop.

```
this.db.collection("Countries").doc("AU")
    .collection("cPostcode").doc(this.searchby)
    .collection(this.shop).where(how, '==', true)
    .onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
            shop.push(doc.data());
        })
    });
    console.log('shop.length', shop.length, 'Shop', shop);
    if (shop.length) {
        this.shopList = shop; .........
```

I use `shop.length > 0` to know if any data is returned, but even though there are 2 items in the array, `shop.length` equals to 0.

Output from the console log shows `length:2`-

```
shop.length 0 shop []
    0:{ABN: "1", ACN: "2"}
    1:{ABN: "3", ACN: "4"}
    length:2
    __proto__:Array(0)
```

I have tried putting a flag in the forEach, but it goes out of scope so does the  "this.count" variable I tried. I have been working on this on and off for days. I have googled this problem and general Typescript help, but no one else seems to have this problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you subscribing to incoming data, and checking its length before it arrives?

Comment: `shop.length` is outside of a asynchronous operation...that's your problem.

Comment: but the console log which is before my if statement works why?

Comment: Analogy: why is my bread not toasted right after I put it in the toaster? Answer: because it will only be toasted when the toaster tells you that it has finished toasting the bread. I.e. once the `function (querySnapshot)` has been called, asynchronously, after the db has loaded all the data from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *reliably* get the length, you need to make sure you wait for a result.

```
  this.db.collection("Countries").doc("AU")
    .collection("cPostcode").doc(this.searchby)
    .collection(this.shop).where(how, '==', true)
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        // In here, we have data
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            shop.push(doc.data());
        });

        console.log('shop.length', shop.length, 'Shop', shop);

        // Therefore, shop.length should work _reliably_
        if (shop.length) {
            alert(shop.length);
        }
  });
```

Alternatives include using promises, or calling a function when you have the result (rather than just chucking all the code inside that callback function).